# Send data along with html file using res.render() in express.js/node.js

Tags: node.js, express

How to access variable `"name"` in `index.html` file using `res.render`?

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render('index.html',{name: "xyz"});
});
```

Following is the example of codeigniter, I want to achieve same in node.js:

```
$data["name"] = "xyz"
$this->load->view("index", $data);
```

I can access `"name"` using `$name` in `index.html` while working in codeigniter. How to access the `"name"` variable in `index.html` while using node.js?

Comment: You will need to use a template engine for that. Check https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html.

Comment: Thanks Hosar. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I used their example of a "simple template engine": https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html  I thought it was very easy to understand and implement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to use something like `$ npm install pug --save` for that. Then you can make a 'Pug template file named `index.pug` in the `views` directory' (or in the directory of your existing `index.html` file) This template should contain the following:

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= name
```

Then in your nodeJS file you can use `res.render` like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { name: 'xyz' })
})
```

Here are the docs I used (from the comment) https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question was how to send extra data, not how to feed the index file with some data.